# ARC and varargs causes BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, variadic-functions

I am going through a list of varargs and when I reach the last object in the list I always get a `BAD_ACCESS` error. I strongly assume that it is  an [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) related issue.

This is what I do:

```
-(NSString *)replaceTokensWithStrings:(NSString *)firstKey, ... {

        va_list _arguments;
        va_start(_arguments, firstKey);

        for (NSString *_currentArgument = firstKey; _currentArgument != nil; _currentArgument = va_arg(_arguments, NSString*)) {
            NSLog(@"%@", _currentArgument);
        }

        va_end(_arguments);

    return nil;
}
```

I have to somehow tell the compiler to retain the result returned by `va_arg` but I can't seem to figure out where and how to apply this paradigm.

**Update 1:** This is how I call my method:

```
[@"Hello <firstname> <lastname>" replaceTokensWithStrings:
  @"firstname", @"Peter",
  @"lastname", "Smith", 
  nil];
```

**Update 2:** I updated my question and added an error I made to reveal what I've actually done wrong. See my answer below.

Comment: why do you have different types on 'value' and in va_arg(strings,id)?

Comment: If you get it on the last object, then it seems like you're just accessing out of bounds. What did zombies tell you?

Comment: Do you actually pass NULL or nil as the last argument?

Comment: @AndersK I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @H2CO3: I pass nil, see updated answer.

Comment: You're passing parms in pairs, yet your loop above isn't distinguishing odd and even.  Lots of room for slip-ups there.

Comment: Btw why do your function returns `void *` yet you don't actually return anything from it?

Comment: Your loop as shown above actually starts processing on the *second* argument, skipping the first one (which is `str1`). It shouldn't matter with the exact code you posted, but since your regular function needs an even number of arguments, that might be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a varargs list in C you need to somehow specify the number of items  in the list or identify the last item -- the language does not do it for you.  This can be via a format statement -- number of args matches number of format items -- or some other scheme.  The default scheme is to end the parameter list in the calling statement with `nil` or `NULL`.

If you look at the definitions of things like `NSArray arrayWithObjects`, the list must always be terminated with `nil`.

Comment: But I get BAD_ACCESS __before__ the last item was logged to the console and I have passed `nil` as the last argument. I updated my answer with the call of the function.

Comment: @Besi -- Then you've got something else going on, unrelated to the varargs.

Comment: @Besi -- (But note that NSLog messages are buffered to a degree and may not appear in order relative to BAD_ACCESS messages and the like.)

Comment: I found the answer, it was in fact not the function but a C string instead of an NSString

Comment: This answer is wrong. The reason you get a bad access is because arc is trying to retain the nil value when it is assigned to _currentArgument. add an __unsafe_unretained to your declaration of that variable.

Comment: @BryceBuchanan: No, it is always safe to send any message (including `retain`) to `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

I was thoroughly on the wrong path. The problem was not the function at all but how I called the function (The other participants could not have known this because I did not do the error in my example in my question).

I have updated my question and the actual problem was that I did not pass a list of NSStrings but 5 NSStrings and the **last** one was an normal C String.

The last C string caused the `BAD_ACCESS`:

**BAD:**

```
"Smith"
```

**GOOD:**

```
@"Smith"
```

Now I am embarassed :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with the `ARC` as well, I'm using the following pattern and it works fine for me, I've never experienced any issue with it, it might help you:

```
- (void)workingWithDictionaries:(NSDictionary *)dictionary, ... {

    va_list _arguments;
    va_start(_arguments, dictionary);

    for (NSDictionary *_currentArgument = dictionary; _currentArgument != nil; _currentArgument = va_arg(_arguments, NSDictionary*)) {
        NSLog(@"%@", _currentArgument);
    }

    va_end(_arguments);
}
```

Comment: You're right, the function was fine, I found the error. I used "" instead of @"" :-/

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue today, and can tell you technically it has nothing to do with ARC or retain, but your method declaration/prototype should be

```
-(NSString *)replaceTokensWithStrings:(NSString *)firstKey, ... 
    NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

That way you tell Xcode and C preprocessor to use the MACRO and asks always to finish with 'nil' so it stops va_arg() from accessing a wrong position (BAD_ACCESS)

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with ARC. va_arg does not check that it arrived at the end of the list, so will return a pointer to the memory block after the list, which can be anything. Hence the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Generally you give the amount of arguments as extra parameter, something like:

```
-(void *)replaceTokensWithNumberOfStrings:(int)numStrings strings:(NSString *)str1, ... {
```

Then use the `numStrings` in your `while` loop.

Comment: It's more common, in Objective-C, to terminate the list with `nil`.

Comment: @HotLicks: Depends on the arg types. If they're objects, use `nil`. If they're classes, use `Nil`. If they're any other kind of pointer, use `NULL`.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan -- Of course, `nil` and `NULL` are the same value -- you can use either, though it's a formality to use `nil` for obj-c objects, `NULL` for other pointers.

Comment: @HotLicks: The idea is that they each represent a different concept: an invalid object, an invalid class reference, or an invalid dumb pointer. Making the distinction in code leads to more readable code. (:

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan -- *If* the convention is adhered to with any regularity.

Comment: @HotLicks: Which it *should be*. ;)

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan -- But rarely is.  I'd be happier if people would just write reasonable comments in their code.

Comment: @HotLicks: I guess I'm just anal-retentive about it. Part of my unique charm.

Comment: @HotLicks: it also depends on the nature of the arguments. Terminating with `nil` (obviously) prevents you from passing `nil` as some of the arguments. If you need to be able to pass `nil` arguments, you need some other pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting an id type from a va_arg return (in this example, NSString*) and it returns a nil value, a crash will occur. This is because arc is trying to retain the nil that is returned.

to avoid this add __unsafe_unretained to the variable you are assigning to.